# Throw an error from within a node connection and catch it in the server error handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling

I would like to handle the case where I don't like the format of the incoming data by throwing a server level error.

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function(c) {
  c.on('data', function() {
    // ***THROW ERROR***
  });
});

server.on('error', function (e) {
    // ***CATCH IT****
});

server.listen(8124);
```

The example is a quick modification to a copy and paste from the node documentation.

I have tried `throw new Error("error");` to no avail!

Comment: Node.js version 0.8 will be out very soon, and it will support [Domains](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.7.12/api/domain.html), which may be worth looking into

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the answer is simple.

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function(c) {
  c.on('data', function() {
    c.server.emit('error', '!!!simple!!!');
  });
});

server.on('error', function (e) {
    // ***CATCH IT****
});

server.listen(8124);
```